# changing pch with lines in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot several lines on a graph and have them use different `pch`:

```
plot(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=3)              
lines(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=1)    
lines(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=2)
lines(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=3)
lines(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=4)
lines(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=5)
```

However, all of the `lines` commands seem to plot using he same plotting character ignoring the `pch` parameter.  What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default `type=` for lines is `l` that makes only line. To plot line and symbol add `type="b"` or `type="o"` to function `lines()`.

```
plot(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=3)              
lines(1:10, sample(1:10,10), pch=1,type="o")
```

`type="o"` means that line will go "inside" the symbol and `type="b"` means that line will end before symbol.

Comment: awesome, thanks! what does "overplotted points and lines" mean? that's what type `o` stands for in the docs

Comment: also, is it possible to not have the `pch` be at every point plotted but rather on only some points so the lines don't look too busy?

Comment: @Alex for the second question - you will have to combine function lines() without pch and function points() to plot just part of points